# SQL query should not return rows that contain null values in pivot table

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I have created a query using a pivot table to extract some metadata (from my wordpress database) for latitude and longitude values associated with posts. I would like to only return posts that have these particular pieces of metadata, and ignore all other posts, but I am unable to filter out those posts that don't have values or these meta keys. Here is my SQL:

```
SELECT wp_posts.ID,   
wp_posts.post_title, wp_posts.post_modified_gmt,
MAX(CASE WHEN wp_postmeta.meta_key = "_wp_geo_longitude" then wp_postmeta.meta_value ELSE NULL END) as longitude,
MAX(CASE WHEN wp_postmeta.meta_key = "_wp_geo_latitude" then wp_postmeta.meta_value ELSE NULL END) as latitude
FROM wp_posts JOIN wp_postmeta  ON ( wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.ID)  
WHERE wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'                  
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID, wp_posts.post_title;
```

I have tried adding the following to the WHERE clause with zero effect:

```
WHERE longitude IS NOT NULL
WHERE wp_postmeta.meta_value IS NOT NULL
```

And variations of that, but all posts are still returned, regardless of null values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a `having` clause:

```
having longitude is not null and latitude is not null
```

This is a situation where the `join` method of pivoting might be more efficient:

```
SELECT p.ID, p.post_title, p.post_modified_gmt,
       lng.meta_value as longitude, lat.meta_value as latitude
FROM wp_posts p JOIN
     wp_postmeta lat
     ON wp_postmeta.post_id = p.ID AND lat.meta_key = '_wp_geo_latiitude' JOIN
     wp_postmeta lng
     ON wp_postmeta.post_id = p.ID AND lng.meta_key = '_wp_geo_longitude'
WHERE p.post_status = 'publish';
```

In general, I prefer the aggregation method more than the join method because it is more flexible.  However, you are only getting two fields *and* you want to ensure that both are there.  That means that the option of using `join`s is quite reasonable in this case.

Comment: thanks!! I will accept this answer as soon as I am able.

Comment: Do you need dummy aggregates (`having min(longitude)...`) or does MySQL do something special there?

Comment: @shawnt00 . . . The full query has no aggregation.  It assumes that the latitude and longitude appear at most once.